# Linq ToDictionary string.split to (.Key, .Value)

Tags: c#

Is it possible to turn this into a single line LINQ query?

```
var columnHeaderToForeignKeys = "column1:Apple,Column2:Bannana,Column3:Apple";

// Can this be converted to a LINQ query?
var headerToForeignKeyPairs = columnHeaderToForeignKeys.Split(',');
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var pair in headerToForeignKeyPairs)
{
    var values = pair.Split(':');
    lookup.Add(values[0], values[1]);
}
```

I seem to be falling down on the ability to take the values of the string split and use them as the key and value:

i.e. how to include `columnHeaderToForeignKeys.Split(':')` in `ToDictionary<string,string>(x => x, x => x)`

I've resorted to doing this:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ColumnHeadersToForeignKeys.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(x => { var values = x.Split(':'); lookup.Add(values[0], values[1]); });
```

however, I'm still curious if this can be accomplished in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
var lookup = columnHeaderToForeignKeys.Split(',')
    .Select(pair=> pair.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(x=>x[0], x=>x[1]);
```

Here we split the string into the ":"-delimited strings, then split each of such a string into key-value pair and then build a dictionary from this pairs.

Note: no errors handling here. So, in case of the incorrect format you may get exception.

Comment: Thank you!! Looks so simple now that I see it but I don't use LINQ much, so it clearly didn't occur to me I could place the second string.split() there, but makes perfect sense now that I see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
var lookup2 =
    (
        from pair in columnHeaderToForeignKeys.Split(',')
        select pair.Split(':')
    ).ToDictionary(
        values => values[0],
        values => values[1]);
```

Comment: ooh, I haven't used the SQL like query expressions since moving on from VB.NET more than a few years ago now. Thanks for the reply and this is certainly a good option for those who like to use that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another:

```
        var columnHeaderToForeignKeys = "column1:Apple,Column2:Bannana,Column3:Apple";
        var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        columnHeaderToForeignKeys.Split([':', ','])
           .Aggregate((c, n) => {if (c is null) return n; lookup[c] = n; return null;});
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of .Aggregate() but I'm sure I'll find somewhere to use it. Thanks.

Comment: `Aggregate` is not very intuitive in usage and consumes more of your brain wax ;) But it is often pretty effective in terms of requesting less memory allocation and also less iterations over your source data.